# Creating a <p> element and changing style in same function

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, appendchild

Hope you're all having a good day.

I'm using "createElement" and "appendChild" to make a paragraph inside of a div.

The code looks like this (sorry for the crude work):

```
var para = document.createElement("p");
para.id = "cursorText";
var node = document.createTextNode(rand);
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("cursorPos");
element.appendChild(para);
```

This creates the paragraph and puts a random word inside of it, and appends it to the div "cursorPos".

It creates an element like the following:

```
<p id="cursorText">Hello StackOverflow</p>
```

The text inside the id para is changed with every click of a button (to a random word from an array) and the goal is to have it fade out after every click.

I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("cursorText");
elem.style.transition = "opacity 2.0s linear 1s";
elem.style.opacity = "0";
```

but it keeps telling me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" @ Line 40 AKA the line that starts elem.style.transition...

please bear in mind the following: The 2 attributes (creating the text node and the animation) have to be in the same function. I've already tried it in a separate function and it did not work.

thanks for reading this cryptic mess, any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Where is the element with id "para"? You don't show one, so your `elem` variable will be `null`.

Comment: Why are you using `getElementById` if you already have `para` (I gathered that `para` and `elem` are supposed to be the same thing?) And the ID is `cursorText`, not `para`, so you're getting a `null` from the `getElementById`...

Comment: @nnnnnn para is the var for the paragraph attribute with ID "cursorPos", I was trying to have it make more sense so you would all understand but I fixed it now.

Comment: @Amadan para is the var for the paragraph creation. elem is the var for whole thing. changing "elem" to "para" just does the same thing as if I made another function and did it that way (which doesn't work either). I edited the question so it made sense.

Comment: It does not. I have no idea what you mean by "the whole thing"; but your changed code now makes it explicit that they are the same thing (a `<p>` whose `id` is `"cursorText"`. Why not just skip `elem`, and assign `para.style...` directly? Or, as Aetricity advises, `para.className`?

Comment: Oh I understand, yes. This would make it more compact so I'll give it a try. Thanks for the input have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the ID as "cursorText", instead of "para".

Also, I would personally recommend you create a CSS class, and set the class attribute on the new object to match that CSS class with all of the changes you want to make to the newly created paragraph.

Comment: Oh nice well spotted. I shouldn't use IDs that are so similar. Thanks a lot fella :)

Comment: On another note, since this was an isolated incident of being the wrong ids should I delete this topic/thread/question as it may just confuse anyone looking for a different answer?

Comment: If you want, but it's up to you whether or not you want to keep it. It could serve as a reminder to make sure your ID corresponds with your name.

Comment: I'll delete it. Thanks for your help my friend.

Answer (score 0):

when you made your variable elem, you told to get by an id you never initialized. If you look at your para class you'll notice your outputted id is 
id="cursorText"
Though when you tried to stylize, you told it to grab 
id="para". 
Therefore you you received null.... quick fix would be to just change you id query function. i.e.

> var elem = document.getElementById("cursorText");

Comment: Yes this is true. Thanks for the reply.